# Cacti can't connect to mysql

Tags: cacti

I got cacti running the mysql monitoring templates (http://mysql-cacti-templates.googlecode.com/files/better-cacti-templates-1.1.8.tar.gz).  I have multiple servers with each running multiple mysql instances on different ports.  I'm getting tons of errors along the lines of

> "WARNING: Result from CMD not valid. Partial Result: MySQL: Lost
>   connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet',
>   system error: 111 "

The weird thing is some of the checks are working properly.  It doesn't seem to be 100% failure per host or per port.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should check your ports configurations as well as try to increase maximum number of connections allowed by adding in your configuration file the following

```
max_connection=N
```

where N is large enough. Then restart mysql. You can also see here (http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=44773). If it is your question there, probably it is better to post here that you've resolved your problem and what was the matter.